# changing a string in json with python

Tags: python

so I am trying to change every "cat" word with "dog"
but when I try to execute my code it just doesn't change anything

here is my code `catisnotpillar.py`

```
import json
import re

with open("catisnotpillar.json", "r+") as f:
    cattext = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    cattext.replace("cat\b", "dog")
    f.write(cattext)
    print(cattext)
```

here is the json file `catisnotpillar.json`

```
{
    "dog": "bob",
    "doga": "dog-eater",
    "animals": [
      "dog",
      "dog",
      "bat",
      "cat",
      "caterpillar"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: `cattext.replace` returns a copy with the replaced text (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) - you throw that away and write the original text to the file

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you'd like to handle "cat", I changed `cat\b` to `"cat"` so it only matches strings.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open("catisnotpillar.json", "r+") as f:
    cattext = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    cattext = cattext.replace('"cat"', '"dog"')
    f.write(cattext)
    print(cattext)
```

Output:

```
{
    "dog": "bob",
    "doga": "dog-eater",
    "animals": [
      "dog",
      "dog",
      "bat",
      "dog",
      "caterpillar"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("catisnotpillar.json", "r+") as f:
    cattext = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    cattext.replace("\"cat\"", "\"dog\"")
    f.write(cattext)
    print(cattext)
```

This

```
"\"cat\""
```

matches all the occurrences of

```
"cat"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import json

count = 0
with open("catisnotpillar.json", "r+") as f:
    cattext = json.load(f)
    for i in cattext["animals"]:
        if i == "cat":
            cattext["animals"][count] = "dog"
        count += 1
    f.seek(0)
    json.dump(cattext, f, indent=4)
```

Output

```
{
    "dog": "bob",
    "doga": "dog-eater",
    "animals": [
        "dog",
        "dog",
        "bat",
        "dog",
        "caterpillar"
    ]
}
```